# Append correct JSON data to div based on ID on click

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to create a simple chat using PHP and ajax.

So far I get all the chats into the listing where it displays who it's from, a small preview of the message, and time sent. However, I am stuck at the point where I append the message to the chat box. When I click on preview 1 it should display the chat log of the respective message.

What I have:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "PHP/CHAT/chat.php",
        data: {user_id : user_id},   
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data.messages_array, function(i, data) {
                console.log(data);
                $("#messagesToUser").append('<li style="margin-bottom:15px;" class="active bounceInDown"><a href="#" id="'+data.msg_id+'" class="openChat"><span class="circle"><span class="userFirstLetter">'+data.userFirstName.substring(0,1)+'</span></span></div><div class="friend-name"><strong class="userFirstName">'+data.userFirstName+'</strong></div><div class="last-message text-muted" class="user_message">'+data.message+'</div><small class="time text-muted" class="messageDate">'+data.date_created+'</small><small class="chat-alert label label-danger" class="messageCount"></small></a></li> ');


            });
            $(document).on("click", ".openChat", function (e) {
                var chatID = $(this).attr('id');
                console.log(chatID);
                $("#chats").html('<div id="'+data.msg_id+'" class="chat-message"><ul class="chat" id="correctChatWindows" data-id=""><li class="left clearfix"><span class="chat-img pull-left"><span class="circle"><span class="userFirstLetter" id="fromUserFirstLetter">'+data.userFirstName.substring(0,1)+'</span></span></span><div class="chat-body clearfix"><div class="header"><strong class="primary-font" id="fromUserName">'+data.userFirstName+'</strong><small class="pull-right text-muted"><span id="timeSent">'+data.date_created+'</span> <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></small></div><p id="message">'+data.message+'</p></div></li></ul><div class="chat-box bg-white"><div class="input-group"><input class="form-control border no-shadow no-rounded" placeholder="Type your message here"><span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-success no-rounded" type="button">Send</button></span></div><!-- /input-group -->    </div>  </div>');

            });
            $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");

        },
        error: function(data){
            //this user has not added his information
            $('#content').text('Update unsuccessful!');
        }

    });
```

Console.log correctly logs the msg_id of the message that has been clicked, but I cannot figure out how to append the corresponding data.

Thanks

Comment: you need to put the data in the id right?why not do `$('#'+data.msg_id).html('data here')`

Comment: @guradio where should I put it? it would be awesome if you could explain a little further. I am still learning all that.

Comment: instead of this `$("#chats")......` use `$('#'+data.msg_id).html('data here')` use same just change the first part

Answer (score 0):

In Your chat box you will have a place to show text right. soo you will have like a div with an unique id for each message that happens. So you can do it like :

```
<body>
    <div id="chat"> 
        <div id="msg1"></div>
        <div id="msg2"></div>
        <div id="msg3"></div>
        <div id="msg4"></div>
        <div id="msg5"></div>
    </div>
<script>
var your_divs = [ "msg1", "msg2", "msg3", "msg4", "msg5" ];
var msg_obj_with_ids = { msg1: 'some msg', msg2: 'some msg', msg3: 'some msg', msg4: 'some msg', msg5: 'some msg' };

jQuery.each( msg_obj_with_ids, function( your_divs, msg_obj_with_ids.val ) {
  $( "#" + your_divs ).text( "Message: " + msg_obj_with_ids.val + "." );


});

</script>

</body>
```

In this above example you need to try out the dynamic way to populate the messages to the chat.

See how I have messages in an array. And I am passing it to the html view.
I dont know what technology you are looking for an solution. But this is how you can do. In php you can use a loop to find out the number of msgs by counting an array and then run the loop that many times and simply print all the msgs.

Comment: `$('#'+data.message_id).html('The message')` this is jquery vanilla js would go like `getelementbyid`

Comment: Can you show your front-end bit what are you trying? So I dont have to guess

Comment: this is it. there is nothing else. there is only a div with an id="chats". that is it. My question is that how can I append the correct data to the div.

Comment: Okay. I see, the front-end bit doesn't have any dynamic properties. That is the problem. You can pass key-value pair from Javascript and Jquery. The key could be the msg_id and the value is the message. Depending on number of messages. What you can do is have a for loop under <div id = "chat"></div> something like <p id ="here you will have the id"> </p> And show all the messages.

Comment: I will append my code to give you an idea on how to go about this.